# Error when reading/writing from CAN and sensor simultaneously over I2C

Tags: sensors, i2c, raspberry-pi4

I am using a can board and an IMU MPU6050 to be able use motors while also reading an angle from the IMU.

When using them separately it works, the IMU reads and the CAN can activate and run the motors. The issue arises when both are activated at the same time and the script gives the following error:

```python
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Here are the registers:

```py
# MPU6050 Registers
MPU6050_ADDR = 0x68#0x0c
PWR_MGMT_1 = 0x6B
SMPLRT_DIV = 0x19
CONFIG = 0x1A
GYRO_CONFIG = 0x1B
ACCEL_CONFIG = 0x1C
INT_PIN_CFG = 0x37
INT_ENABLE = 0x38
ACCEL_XOUT_H = 0x3B
ACCEL_YOUT_H = 0x3D
```

And fault messages arises when I try to write a byte to the IMU at the same time as the CAN bus is activated:

```py
# Write to Configuration register
bus.write_byte_data(MPU6050_ADDR, CONFIG, 0)
```

I created a new I2C bus for the IMU which is bus #3 which gives me the addresses 0x68 and 0x0c.

I have checked the wiring which is correct. Otherwise I should get the same error when running them separately.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Are they muxed on the SoC?

Comment: What does that mean? 
I have the CAN on one bus and the IMU on another bus